# How to show Line2D in Qt4 Widget

Tags: python, matplotlib, qt4, pyqt4, data-visualization

I'd like to show a Line2D instance in a Qt4 Widget. But when I run the code, it just show a blank figure.

Here is my code.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

class Qt4MplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    """Class to represent the FigureCanvas widget"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        # plot definition
        self.fig = Figure()
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)

        x = [1,1]
        y=[2,2]
        self.line = Line2D(x, y, marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = 'r', animated = True)
        self.axes.add_line(self.line)
        self.axes.set_xlim((0,3))
        self.axes.set_ylim((0,3))



        # initialization of the canvas
        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, self.fig)
        # set the parent widget
        self.setParent(parent)

        # we define the widget as expandable
        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                               QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        # notify the system of updated policy
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

class ApplicationWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    """Example main window"""
    def __init__(self):
        # initialization of Qt MainWindow widget
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        # set window title
        self.setWindowTitle("Matplotlib Figure in a Qt4 Window With NavigationToolbar")

        # instantiate a widget, it will be the main one
        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)

        # create a vertical box layout widget
        vbl = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        # instantiate our Matplotlib canvas widget
        qmc = Qt4MplCanvas(self.main_widget)
        # instantiate the navigation toolbar
        vbl.addWidget(qmc)
        # set the focus on the main widget
        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        # set the central widget of MainWindow to main_widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)


# create the GUI application
qApp = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
# instantiate the ApplicationWindow widget
aw = ApplicationWindow()
# show the widget
aw.show()
# start the Qt main loop execution, exiting from this script
# with the same return code of Qt application
sys.exit(qApp.exec_())
```

There are two classes in my code. class Qt4MplCanvas is used to draw a Line2D figure. class ApplicationWindow is to write a window and add a widget on it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the problem is in the line (but unfortunately I don't know why...):

```
self.line = Line2D(x, y, marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = 'r', animated = True)
```

I saw a plot by erasing the `animated = True`. This changed the line to:

```
self.line = Line2D(x, y, marker = 'o', markerfacecolor = 'r')
```

This displayed a point with the coordinates (1,2).

I don't know if the plot should change over time, but maybe this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html) helps you with it.

Comment: Thank you very much for reading my code. I was puzzled by the problem for days until you helped me. But I still don't know what does animated mean. The example you linked above is the one which I learned to write my code.  Now I think the problem is how to use Line2D. But few documents and examples can be found.